# Absolute Address for CSS

Tags: php, css, require-once

I have the following file structure on my PHP localhost:

- Root

  - css/

    - main.css
  - admin/

    - admin.php
  - index.php
  - header.php

Both admin.php and index.php are requiring header.php, in which main.css is included like the following:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
        href="<?php echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; ?>/css/main.css" />
```

However, the css file isn't included properly. When I look at the Source Code in Chrome on Mac, The browser has turned that into

```
http://localhost/Users/ljhljh235/Documents/web/hetd/css/main.css
```

in which `http://localhost` is not intended to be here. Could anybody help me on how to build the correct absolute path for the css file?

P.S. My way of including header.php in admin.php and index.php is

```
require_once ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/header.php');
```

And I'm using MAMP 2.1.1.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] is for server side path, use /css/main.css only, it will be relative to the domain ie : http://domain.com/css/main.css

Comment: You're welcome, remember that without starting /, the path is relative from the current path, with one, it is relative from the root.

Comment: You normaly could also try http://<?php echo $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] ?>/css/main.css if ever you really need the complete path